# ng-include doesn't find my page

Tags: angularjs, path, angularjs-ng-include

All my pages are under ***/WEB-INF/views/*** . I used ng-include to include a page in my index.html

```
 <div ng-include="'myPage.html'"></div>
```

but I got

> GET http://localhost:8080/myPage.html 404 (Not Found)

Here my configureViewResolvers :

```
  @Override
    public void configureViewResolvers(ViewResolverRegistry registry) {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".html");

        registry.viewResolver(viewResolver);
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried `<div ng-include="'WEB-INF/views/myPage.html'"></div>` ?

Comment: yes , it doesn't work either

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have `ng-app` before or outside of the `ng-include` 
 , or do it like

```
<div ng-app="" ng-include="'WEB-INF/views/myPage.html'"></div>
```